# Combining lists into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got lists:

```
host = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
user = ['first_user',  'second_user', '-']
time = ['01/01', '02/02', '03/03']
```

I want to have list of dictionaries where each dict looks like below:

```
{'host': 'host1',
 'user': 'firsts_user',
 'time': '01/01'}
```

How would you do that?

Comment: How have you tried to do that, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, the question is not clear enough but I implement this from what I understand;

```
>>> host = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
>>> user = ['first_user', 'second_user', '-']
>>> time = ['01/01', '02/02', '03/03']
>>>
>>> d = []
>>> for i in range(len(host) - 1):
...     d.append({
...         host[i]: host[i + 1],
...         user[i]: user[i + 1],
...         time[i]: time[i + 1]
...     })
...
>>> print(d)
[{'host1': 'host2', 'first_user': 'second_user', '01/01': '02/02'}, {'host2': 'host3', 'second_user': '-', '02/02': '03/03'}]
```

Comment: That is considering all 3 lists are the same length. @Rammb you may want to do some checks to avoid your program to crash if some of the lists are shorter than expected

Comment: Yes, definitely you are right. But I am really not sure if I understand the case clearly. If this is the one @Rammb asks, I will fix the code

Answer (score 1):

Very slight modification of the [Cenk Bircanoglu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800120/5073569) answer where all dictionary keys are fixed rather than having them referring to the follow-up element. I assume that was asked.

```
d = []
for count, el in enumerate(host):
    d.append({
        'host': el,
        'user': user[count] if len(user) >= count+1 else None,
        'time': time[count] if len(time) >= count+1 else None
    })
print(d)
```